# using Python for a solution cannot be handled in JAVA because of slow execution

Tags: java, python, performance

I have 3 millions line of data each has 30 features - it is hard to include all in memory for my computer and slow to process it with learning algorithm - . I want to write a little code that makes random sampling but in JAVA and with my PC configurations it does not work or takes so much times to execute. I know that writing in C or C++ gives better solution but I am also curious about the availability of python for such case. Is it reasonable to use Python in such a case that Java is not working efficiently because of slowness and memory restriction - please do not say to increase heap size or such-?

Comment: dont you see the question from that explanation

Comment: I'm afraid I do understand the exact nature of your question. What problems are you facing and what do you want to do?

Comment: Java is not slower than C/C++/python. If you try to load the whole 3 millions lines at once you will get low performance whatever the language used.

Comment: Instead of maping whole file into memory, scan the file on disk.

Comment: I am sorry but they have almost 30 sec difference with a native file io codes.

Comment: In Java, I have 1.5 bn rows of data with 22 columns which takes minutes to scan and process.  I suspect the problem is how you are processing the data, not the language you use.

Comment: They? It's still unclear what you're trying to do, really. If you see a performance problem, perhaps it's time to profile it? Modern JVMs are not that slow, (contrary to common belief) if used wisely.

Comment: Potentially, if it's a memory problem, Python has pretty good support for easily working on data from files lazily, but it's completely possible to do that in Java as well. In general, Python is likely to be slower than Java for a given task.

Comment: If you are reading, splitting and parsing the data as text every time, I would expect Java to be fairly slow.  The simple answer, is don't do that.  Store the data as binary and memory map the file and it will load into memory in milli-seconds.

Comment: I dont understand you folks... the guy is telling a problem to see the common wisdom's help but you are dealing with the question he is asking. It is a obvious question. If you see it unclear just dont write any even the question is really clear to me.

Comment: Using such interpreted language is not a good choice to deal big files if you don't know any tricks work on these language. Use C or C++ for non-tricked code with good performance and certainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is critical, this is the sort of solution I use.

```
public class SimpleTable {
    private final List<RandomAccessFile> files = new ArrayList<RandomAccessFile>();
    private final List<FloatBuffer> buffers = new ArrayList<FloatBuffer>();
    private final File baseDir;
    private final int rows;

    private SimpleTable(File baseDir, int rows) {
        this.baseDir = baseDir;
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public static SimpleTable create(String baseName, int rows) throws IOException {
        File baseDir = new File(baseName);
        if (!baseDir.mkdirs()) throw new IOException("Failed to create " + baseName);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(baseName + "/rows");
        pw.println(rows);
        pw.close();
        return new SimpleTable(baseDir, rows);
    }

    public static SimpleTable load(String baseName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(baseName + "/rows"));
        int rows = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        br.close();
        File baseDir = new File(baseName);
        SimpleTable table = new SimpleTable(baseDir, rows);
        File[] files = baseDir.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(files);
        for (File file : files) {
            if (!file.getName().endsWith(".float")) continue;
            table.addColumnForFile(file);
        }
        return table;
    }

    private FloatBuffer addColumnForFile(File file) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile rw = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        MappedByteBuffer mbb = rw.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, rows * 8);
        mbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer db = mbb.asFloatBuffer();
        files.add(rw);
        buffers.add(db);
        return db;
    }

    public int rows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public int columns() {
        return buffers.size();
    }

    public FloatBuffer addColumn() throws IOException {
        return addColumnForFile(new File(baseDir, String.format("%04d.float", buffers.size())));
    }

    public FloatBuffer getColumn(int n) {
        return buffers.get(n);
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        for (RandomAccessFile file : files) {
            file.close();
        }
        files.clear();
        buffers.clear();
    }
}

public class SimpleTableTestMain {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        SimpleTable st = SimpleTable.create("test", 3 * 1000 * 1000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            FloatBuffer db = st.addColumn();
            for (int j = 0; j < db.capacity(); j++)
                db.put(j, i + j);
        }
        st.close();

        long mid = System.nanoTime();

        SimpleTable st2 = SimpleTable.load("test");
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            FloatBuffer db = st2.getColumn(i);
            double sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < db.capacity(); j++)
                sum += db.get(j);
            assert sum > 0;
        }

        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to write and %.3f seconds to read %,d rows and %,d columns%n",
                (mid - start) / 1e9, (end - mid) / 1e9, st2.rows(), st2.columns());
        st2.close();
    }
}
```

prints

```
Took 2.070 seconds to write and 2.206 seconds to read 3,000,000 rows and 50 columns
```